# "Statement expected" on else but there's nothing wrong with the code?

Tags: python, pycharm

Getting a "Statement expected" on
else:

I've tried replacing it with elif but that doesnt do the trick, and nothing online has helped me so far.

[image]

It's supposed to just print an error message variable if I dont enter any of the other search results.

```py
if Cmdbar() == "Help":
    os.system('cls')
    print(colored(logo, 'blue'))
    for ItemClassesx in ItemClasses:
        print(colored(ItemClassesx, 'green'))
    Cmdbar()


elif Cmdbar() == "Longswords":
   os.system('cls')
   print(colored(logo, 'blue'))
   for Longswordsx in Longswords:
    print(colored(Longswordsx, 'green'))
Cmdbar()

else:
print(error)
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong, the block `print(error)` under `else:` should be indented.

Comment: I've done that already I forgot to mention it

Comment: Also, since the `Cmdbar()` under the `elif` is not indented, the `else` isn't really attached to the `if/elif` anymore...

Comment: Also, you should try and keep a constant number of spaces for your indentations - 4 is the traditional value for Python.

Comment: Option/Command/L (Mac) or Ctrl/Alt/L (Win/Linux) will automatically sort out the ragged indentation. As with a lot of python, you need to look at the command before the one showing the error as that's usually where the incorrect indentation or missing bracket or quote is.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Else block cannot be kept empty. It must at-least contain 'pass'.

The line 'print(error)' must be indented inside the else block.

Also your 'Cmdbar()' in the elif must be indented.